# How to pass select value to url using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

**how to pass the select dropdown value to url**
Here is what I tried.

```
<select name="value"> 
  <option value="1">1</option> 
  <option value="2">2</option> 
  <option value="4">4</option> 
  <option value="10">10</option> 
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){ $('select').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $('#one').val();
        window.location.href = url+'?&'+value;
}   }); });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with your code. Are you merely looking to simplify it?

Comment: an extra `}` in your code perhaps?

Comment: You could always try actually using the name of the select element you are trying to get the value from, ie, in this case it is called value, and you are trying to access it by using the name one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working thing. Also, I am not sure, what exactly do you mean by "pass select value to URL simply"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var url = "http://www.google.com";
var value = "";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
        value = $(this).val();
        window.location.href = url+'?&'+value;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


Select:
<select name="value"> 
  <option value="1">1</option> 
  <option value="2">2</option> 
  <option value="4">4</option> 
  <option value="10">10</option> 
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RinShanKolayil: If you find this answer useful in solving the question. Please Accept/Upvote it to close the question.

Thanks !

Comment: pls tell me how to get this value to display in php

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.change` instead of `on.click`. Also add an `id` for `select`

```
<select name="value" id="selectedID">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectedID").change(function(){
        var value = $('#selectedID').val();
        window.location.href = url+'?&'+value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear if you want to get the value from option and reload the page with a REQUEST query "value?=" with the selected value, use this code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
      $('select').on('change', function(e)
      {
            var value = $(this).val();
            window.location.href = '?value='+value;
      }); 
});
```

if you want to just replace the url without reloading try replacing the history state, use this code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
  $('select').on('change', function(e)
  {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var urlNow = window.location.href.replace(/\?.*/g,'').replace(/\/$/g,'');
        history.replaceState({},'',urlNow+'/?value='+value);
  });
});
```

Comment: In php use $_GET['value']

Comment: Change the code to this and get the value in php as $_GET['value']

Comment: <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="search.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var url = "search.php";
 var value= "";
$("select").change(function(){
var value=$(this).val();
window.location.href=url+'?&'+'value='+value;
    });
});